# ActivityRecognitionClient from a service

Tags: android

We now have the ActivityRecognitionClient class available to us. The dev docs show how to use it from an activity:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

Is there a way to have the OS notify our app when a particular activity type is encountered? For example, I want my app to be called by the OS whenever the activity type state changes from stopped to biking.

The example makes it seem like we need to use ActivityRecognitionClient with an Activity (or fragment) that's bound by the lifecycle of an application.

Ideally though we could register criteria with the OS, similar to a geofence request. I guess as a workaround we can run a service every N seconds that creates an ActivityRecognitionClient instance, listens to it for a couple seconds, then tears everything down.

Thanks

Comment: any solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with the new client class on a current project. The best I've got so far is to create a foreground service (as my users need to know that the service is running) that sets up the connection to the recognition client and creates the pending intent to an IntentService that does my processing on the detected activity found during updates.

Dependant on your requirements you could send a broadcast (local or otherwise) as the DetectedActivity is parcleable or do what i did which was pass the DetectedActivity back to my foreground service to process in it's onStartCommand.